# Как вытащить определенные теги из бд

Tags: php

Имеется поле(description) в базе данных

```
<img src="images1.png" alt="">
Картинка 1 - Автомобиль Ваз
<img src="images2.png" alt="">
Картинка 2 - Автомобиль УАЗ
<img src="images2.png" alt="">
Картинка 3 - Автомобиль Lada
```

Как вытащить отсюда только img
То есть что бы на выходе я получил

```
<img src="images1.png" alt="">
<img src="images2.png" alt="">
<img src="images3.png" alt="">
```

Comment: Думаю надо поле целиком вытащить из базы, после чего, уже в php извлечь из него img простенькой регуляркой

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

MySQL? Там есть регулярки, чтобы лишнее не тянуть:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE description REGEXP '(<img.+?>)'
```

А по результату уже в PHP обрабатываем:

```
preg_match_all('/(<img.+?>)/is', $result, $matches);
```

Массив $matches будет содержать массив всех тегов img.

Их можно собрать в одну строку вот так:

```
$glued = implode('', $matches);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. `Select description from table` // вытаскиваем с базы
2. `preg_match('#<(.*')>#si', $result, $arr)` // вырезаем нужное
   `$arr[0][0]` // выводим то, что в `<>`